# Regular expression to match any like word

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match all words which user can be used on for example forms such as with black-list on web app as `php`

For an example these words are is in **black-list**

> ask, stackoverflow, hello

Now I want to match them with any similar words, for example:

> a_ks, as_k, as-k, as.k or a.s.k

I found these regex's, but I think it's not correct for my problem:

1:

```
\W*((?i)ask(?-i))\W*
```

2:

```
^((?!ask)[\s\S])*$
```

Comment: @anubhava thats only sample

Comment: Very difficult to make `a_ks` equivalent to `ask`

Comment: There is always a way to go around such blacklisting. What's your purpose ?

Comment: @Rahul yes, i want to filter them with black-list

Comment: A good approach would be to strip off all special characters from the input string and then compare it against the list of blacklist words.

Comment: @Vivek yes sir, your right

Comment: Arbitrarily switching letters as in ask/a_ks isn't something regex can do. For the others, though, would `a.*?s.*?k` suffice? And of course you could specify a length with `{n, n}` if `*?` gives too many false positives.

Comment: Such a blacklisting will either be too easy to circumvent (say `аsk` with a cyrillic `a` for instance, or `a5k` for the leetspeak lovers), or too easily triggered (blocking legitimate words, such as `asok`, or `askew`). Or both.
I remember in High school having `mathsexchange.com` blocked because of the `sex` part in the url...

Answer (score 2):

You can remove special chars from word then match those words with blacklist words. Try following code:

```
<?php

$black_list_words = array("ask", "stackoverflow", "hello");
$words = array("stack_overflow","as_k","as.k","not","good","a.s.k");
foreach($words as $word)
{
    $match_word =  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $word); 
    foreach($black_list_words as $check_word)
    {

        if(strcasecmp($check_word,$match_word) === 0 )
        {
            echo "found :".$check_word." IN ".$word;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

}
?>
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/tqR7J)